# Renamed android app.. problems ensue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I renamed my android app (using eclipse `refactor->rename`) now it crashes before I get to the activity initialisation. Here's the call stack:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417  
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable]    
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I have some native methods in my app but they don't match the signature in `Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean)` so I'm not sure if that's relevant. Besides, I would imagine it would crash when I tried to call that if there was a problem with the native method (at least, that's what happened when I was developing them). I can't get a break point anywhere on this so I'm not sure what's going on or how to debug it. I imagine there is a file somewhere with a cryptic reference to the old project name but I can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: stupid question, but did you check to make sure that your manifest file was also updated? AFAIK refactor->rename doesn't automatically change the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Abatishchev :)

Comment: @Brian: Mine's called 'AndroidManifest.xml' without any reference to the project name. Is there a meta manifest manifest file that refers to that somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just done this myself, I experienced similar (but not exactly the same problems).

The biggest thing problem with doing Refactor > Rename is that it will only manage the naming of the Java portions of your code. It will not update any of the XML (which there is quite a bit in an Android application). You will have to do a search within your project for the old name and manually switch it over to the new name. This includes files such as AndroidManifest.xml as well as others (most likely any XML file). In addition, if you changed the package structure of your classes, you will have to update that as well (though that does not appear to be what you did in this case).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to grep the project (rather than use Vista search which doesn't seem to want to search inside text files, even when it suggests it)

Comment: @Tim - Ah, yeah. Definitely would recommend just using Eclipse's file search and use the search filter of *

Answer (score 1):

I would check your native methods since the naming of native methods tends to depend on Java class names.

Also, you will have to change names in your AndroidManifest.xml to reflect your changes.

Otherwise, could you post the actual error message accompanying the stack trace?

Comment: Here's the full stack trace. I've noticed something odd - the old name of the app is at the top of the trace still, even though I've specifically right-clicked and debugged the app with the new name. Something is retaining a reference to the old name but I can't see what.

Comment: `TimApp-Android2.1 [Android Application] 
 DalvikVM[localhost:8602] 
  Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
   ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417 
   ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512 
   ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
   ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863 
   ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 `

Comment: did you change the names in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: `Looper.loop() line: 123 
   ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363 
   Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
   Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
   ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860 
   ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
   NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method`

Comment: Sorry for the code spam, trying to fit the whole stack on there and haven't got a hang of the tags :( There are no references to the old or new project names in the AndroidManifest.xml  file, only to the package which remains the same ('tim.app')

Comment: Argh, no luck. I've grepped the lot; there are no references to the old name anywhere other than in Eclipse's copious logs. I've removed all of my NDK binaries, remade my C headers, cleaned the solution, renamed every last hidden reference to the old project name and sacrificed an ungulate. Is it just me or does the NDK seem really fragile and require crazy hoops just to get it working? That said, I'm not 100% sure that it is the NDK that's causing these problems. Thanks very much for the comments so far - they've givven me something to do and I've learned some things in the process.

Comment: Hang in there. What about breakpointing and then stepping through with the Eclipse debugger?

Comment: Tried that, can't get a break point in early enough. It seems to be crashing in whatever setup code is called when an application starts. Unless I'm missing something Activity::onCreate is the place to catch the program earliest, right?

Comment: If I comment out all of my NDK code, it still crashes in the same way. This is driving me nuts, what could it be? At this rate, I'm going to have to make a new project and copy my code over. I don't want to do that though as I'd like to know what's going wrong here in order to prevent it happening again (and hopefully getting a fuller picture of android in the process)

Comment: I've tried a different emulator. Other android projects also work, just not the one I renamed. If it didn't crash _before_ startup, maybe I'd be able to debug it. If I do manage to find a solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't renaming the project that caused the problem and the NDK wasn't to blame - that was a wild goose chase because I saw the string 'native method' in the call stack.

The problem was that I'd renamed the activity *as well* and that did need renaming in the manifest, just like you guys had said.

I think there's a lesson here for refactoring too much at a time and too late at night!
Anyway, problem solved! Thank you guys very much for your time.